# Angular input directive not passing value

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm trying to write a directive that, behind the scenes, converts commas into dots so the input in input fields can be save correctly to the database. I still want the field to show the unedited input though.

I got the following:

```
App.directive('input', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelController) {
        if (iAttrs.type !== 'commasallowed') return;

        iElement.unbind('input');
        iElement.bind('input', function() {

            ngModelController.$render = function() {
                console.log("start render");
                iElement.val(scope.screenValue);
            };

            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.screenValue = iElement.val();
                scope.toDb = parseFloat(scope.screenValue.toString().replace(",", "."));

                ngModelController.$setViewValue(scope.toDb);
                console.log(ngModelController.$viewValue);

                ngModelController.$render();
            });
        });
    }
};
});
```

When I start typing in the input field, the console.log in line 25 logs the correct value of ngModelController.$viewValue is correctly logged as a number with dots instead of commas,
but when I process the form only the number before the dot is saved....

Comment: Maybe use formatters and parsers services of angular can help you. It's more angular way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the help,I'm quite new to Angular and wasn't aware of those functies. So no need for me to write all that mess myself, it's a very simple directive now.